# creating a leaderboard for noughts and crosses game

Tags: python, json, dictionary, file-handling, txt

```
{"Bob": 50,"Jane": 2,"Sarah": 5, "Amelia": 20}
```

I have a txt file like this and I wrote a code to be able to get different players name and score that will be saved to the dictionary from highest to lowest.but when ever a new player saves their name&score, my txt file create a new dictionary like this ("

```
{"tie": 0}{"bobby": 0}
```

").
here is my code>

```
import json
import os
def save_score(score):
    filename = 'leaderboard.txt'
    player = input('what is your name')
    dictionary = {}
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        with open("leaderboard.txt", "a") as leaderboard:
            dictionary[player]=score
            json.dump(dictionary,leaderboard)
        print("score"+ " " + str(score)+ " "+ "for" + " " +str(player)+ " "+"saved.")
    return
```

I want to be able to append and also update the new players name and score to the existing dictionary.
eg. if bob plays and gets 5{"bob": 5}, and he plays again and gets 7. instead of creating a new dictionary for bob it should update {"bob": 5} to {"bob": 6}.
and also if new users play the game, their name and score should be added to the same dictionary with bob. {"bob": 5}. instead of creating a new dictionary.
so instead of this {"bob": 5} {"tina": 5}. I want to have this {"bob": 5, "tina": 1}.
please how do I go on about it?. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First load the scores from the file with [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load), then change the score of the specific player, then save the scores back to the file with [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump).

Opening the file twice with different modes is necessary to overwrite the old dictionary in the file with the new dictionary rather than appending to the file.

```py
with open("leaderboard.txt", "r") as leaderboard:
    dictionary = json.load(leaderboard)

dictionary[player] = score

with open("leaderboard.txt", "w") as leaderboard:
    json.dump(dictionary,leaderboard)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much!. I was able to update the players score and also add new players. although a new dictionary keeps getting created. please how can I stop that from happening. I want just 1 dictionary. thanks in advance!.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much. I was able to do that after a while. appreciate your help.thanks